# Perl URL replace

Tags: string, perl, replace

I am trying to achieve following task,

1. Extract all urls from the text.
2. If domain belongs to white list, then replace them with modified urls.

Following is the code.

```
$text = '<a href="http://www.amazon.de/Lenovo-Moto-Smartphone-Android-schwarz/dp/B01FLZC8ZI"><img src="http://www.testurl.de/Sasdfhopr.jpg" width="80%"></a>';

$regex = '(http|ftp|https):\/\/([\w_-]+(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)+))([\w.,@?^=%&:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&\/~+#-])?';

@whiteList = ("www.amazon.de");

while ($text =~ /$regex/g) {
       # regex result has following groups as matches
       # $1 = scheme
       # $2 = domain
       # $3 = query parameters

       # check if domain is in white list
       if ( grep( /^$2$/, @whiteList ) ) {
           # build new url
           $new = "http://test.xyz.pqr/url=".$1."://".$2.$3;

           # recreate old url
           $old = $1."://".$2.$3;

           # replace it here, but its not replacing
           $text =~ s/$old/$new/g;

           # but as an example replacing 
           # domain name with test, its working. 
           # it appears to be something to with back slash or forward 
           # slashes
           $text =~ s/$2/test/g;
         }
    } print $text;
```

Any help or hint would be great. As I am new to perl programming.

Comment: Missing `use strict; use warnings;`.

Comment: @melpomene well, after putting strict and warnings. I got warnings like 'my is not used'. But still issue is not solved. Thanks.

Comment: @bharatesh: `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` don't magically fix your program, they draw your attention to errors in your code, which you then must fix yourself. Do that, and post your new code if you are still unable to fix it yourself.

Comment: @SinanÜnür: *"Use `Regexp::Common`"* That was my first thought, but having tried in the past to do something similar, I found that `Regexp::Common::URI` is in a half-finished state. It doesn't seem to support an authority or a fragment on the URL, and if you use `$RE{URI}{HTTP}{-keep}` then the captured fields aren't documented. I started to assemble a solution for the OP along those lines, but realised that I needed `URI` as well and soon gave up. I may write to the maintainer to see if this can be fixed.

Comment: @SinanÜnür: The problem is that `URI` can't find the URLs in a block of text on its own. As I described, I considered a solution using both `Regexp::Common::URI` and `URI`, but it quickly became untenable. It's entirely possible that I have made a mistake, but I couldn't find it and so have emailed the maintainer. If you want to experiment then my example was `http://user:pass@www.example.com:88/path?query#fragment` which the module recognizes but doesn't split into parts correctly using the `{-keep}` option. Even if it did, those parts are undocumented.

Comment: @bharatesh: As far as I can tell, you want to search for all URLs in a document and replace them with a different host name if the original host name is in `@white_list`. Is that right?

Comment: @SinanÜnür: That's the primary option of course. Any substring of an HTML document that happens to look like a URL may well not be eligible, and the OP is probably looking for the contents of `href` or `src` attributes. However they seem to have gone silent, and it may be that we will never know.

Comment: @Borodin thank you for your advice. I know using use of strict or warnings won't fix any problems. At least any body who does programming can understand without any doubt. I am here to discuss, some issues as I am not a perl developer. Otherwise I would not asked in first place. Well please read the post carefully before you come to any conclusions. Try to read the comments in the code, Try to run the example code, infact it works without any issues. The problem start to appears when text contains line breaks or empty lines.

Comment: @Borodin The set of environment I am working is a lagacy code. Had tons or restrictions.

Answer (score 3):

I would use [`Regexp::Common`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Common) in conjunction with [`Regexp::Common::URI`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Common::URI) to locate the URLs, and 
[`URI`](https://metacpan.org/pod/URI) to parse and transform them

Your very minimal data sample doesn't help, but here is a proof of my idea using that data

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Regexp::Common 'URI';
use URI;
use List::Util 'any';

use constant NEW_HOST => 'test.xyz.pqr';

my $text = <<'END';
<a href="http://www.amazon.de/Lenovo-Moto-Smartphone-Android-schwarz/dp/B01FLZC8ZI">
<img src="http://www.testurl.de/Sasdfhopr.jpg" width="80%">
</a>
END

my @white_list = qw/ www.amazon.de /;

$text =~ s{ ( $RE{URI}{HTTP} ) } {
    my $uri = URI->new($1);
    my $host = $uri->host;
    $uri->host(NEW_HOST) if any { $host eq $_ } @white_list;
    $uri->as_string;
}exg;

print $text, "\n";
```

#### output

```html
<a href="http://test.xyz.pqr/Lenovo-Moto-Smartphone-Android-schwarz/dp/B01FLZC8ZI">
<img src="http://www.testurl.de/Sasdfhopr.jpg" width="80%">
</a>
```

Comment: The code already works without any issues in any of online compilers.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to run your code, since it looks cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

The URL in `$old` contains characters that Perl's regex engine treats as part of the pattern, not as literal characters, when you use it inside the pattern match.

```
$text =~ s/$old/$new/g;
```

You need to escape those. You can do that with the `\Q` and `\E` commands.

```
$text =~ s/\Q$old\E/$new/g;
```

That should do the trick, assuming the rest of your code is working, which I have not tried.